# How to precompile C++ headers which do not end with .h

Tags: c++, header

I want to know how can we precompile the header files like `<iostream>` and `<algorithm>` which do not end with .h ?

Earlier I was using the `<bits/stdc++.h>` library which I precompiled using `g++ stdc++.h` through terminal and was working fine. But since it is not supported everywhere so I want to use the standard headers in my c++ program and precompile those headers for faster compilation.

I have found the path and I was executing the normal `g++ iostream`, however I am getting a syntax error. I have tried searching for the issue but i'm not getting it. The official site had mentioned using `-x` flag but I still don't know how to use it as I'm new to C++ environment.

I have tried using `-o` flag for output file but the error is always the same.
`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:iostream:1: syntax error collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

My intensions for doing this is just to decrease the compilation time.

GCC version
`g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0`

Comment: Do you really have a problem with compilation time in your project that introduces the need to do that yourself? Compilers already cache the compilation results themselves.  Precompiled headers can for sure be useful in really huge codebases. If you have compile-time problems in small to medium projects, then you probably include more then you actually need.

Comment: For `gcc` you can use the `-include` in your build script to include `bits/stdc++.h`  (or any other precompiled header) before any other header. So you can indeed use precompiled headers provided by the compiler in a portable way, but ou mus not include it directly in your source code but use compiler flags to do so.

Comment: @t.niese  I don't have a big or medium project, I am just running a single cpp file from terminal. All  I wanted to know is that if there's a way to precompile the `iostream` header in the same way as `bits/stdc++.h` and have a `.gch` file of it. I am doing it for faster execution of my cpp programs for competitive coding purpose.

Currently it's taking me about 20 seconds to do it but after precompiling bits/stdc++.h its taking 4seconds. But since it is not supported in some OJ's so I wnt to do the same for `iostream` ` vector` `alorithm` header files, if posssible.